# delete strings from file bash

Tags: string, bash

I have a file with tons of call logs and I am trying to clean it up using bash.  I figured out how to search for a string and delete the entire line it is on but that isn't what I want to accomplish.

I want to search for a string as an example:

- There are tons of MAC address in the file and I want to remove them all `MAC:00-0A-DD-84-01-33`
- There is also a call ID at the beginning of each line that looks like:  `354469805` or `354469894` and I want to remove all of those as well.

I'm just starting in bash so please excuse my ignorance.  I am entering 2 lines of the call log below for clarification.  I want to delete the 3544 number, the MAC address, and the word Telepacific.

```
354469725   06/24/2013  09:34   00:03:26    Chante Squires      105 TelePacific     MAC:00-0A-DD-84-01-1D   TelePacific                 17025290701 1   
354469732   06/24/2013  09:59   00:01:16    Chante Squires      105 TelePacific     MAC:00-0A-DD-84-01-1D   TelePacific                 12132238375 1
```

Comment: Please add a few sample lines of input to the question.

Comment: `sed -i '/regex-pattern/d' file.ext`

Comment: I tried sed -i '/"Telepacific"/d' Nichole24-25 > Nichole
but got..
sed: 1: "Nichole24-25": extra characters at the end of N command

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/^[0-9]\{9\}\|MAC:[0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\([-\:][0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)\{5\}//g' input.log
```

Between the `'s/` and `//g'` is a regular expression that matches the removal criteria in your question. The `s` flag in front means "search and replace" the regular expression. The `//` means replace the regular expression with nothing. The `g` flag at the end means "replace all matches" if they occur more than once in a line. Finally, the `-i` switch means "edit the files in-place".

This solution assumes that your call IDs are all 9 digits and that the MAC address has six groups of two hexadecimal digits separated by dashes or colons.

Answer (score 1):

One way with `awk` (you will loose extra tabs space, every field will be separated by single space):

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++) if(8>i || i>10) printf "%s ", $i; print $NF}' log
```